# Razor Pages Core - Update Model or pass additional data back to Post Method

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, razor-pages

I hope I can ask this question concisely...

Pretty new to Razor Pages using .Net Core but started a project and hope I can find help on a current problem. I am sure there may be a few ways of solving this problem so think it best to describe what I am looking to achieve compared to what I currently know.

To give a bit more detail, I have a Model called **Entry**. Each **Entry** can have many **EntryImages**. So, In my Razor Pages project, on the edit screen for Entries, I want to be able to add new EntryImages (one at a time).

So, on the **Entry** Edit page, I have a modal popup containing a file selector which allows me to pass an image file back to the Post method on Submit using **IFormFile**:

[image]

In code behind I then take this file and put the image info into an **EntryImage** which goes into the **Entry**, before passing to the database:

[image]

However, I also want to be able to add a comment against the image I have just passed to the database. This is where my understanding falls short. I hoped I could just update the Model in the page like so (this is a test example):

[image]

Where I try to add a new **EntryImage** to the model **Entry** - but back in the post method in code behind, the model does not contain the new **EntryImage** added.

I know my attempt is messy but hope it gives a good idea of what I am looking to achieve. I feel there is a really simple way of doing what I need but for trying, I cant seem to find the right answer yet.

Comment: Why don't you pass the image along with the comment to the backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another input text behind the file selector:

```
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="files" type="file" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-row">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input name="comment" type="text"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

Then in the post method, have another parameter to accept the comment value:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IFormFile files, string comment)
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Marked answer feels correct and best practice. I also however found that you can get the value from a control by its name in code-behind using:

`string comment = (string)Request.Form["txtComment"]`;

where **txtComment** is the name of the text input control.